# What qualifies as a first generation college student?

Tags: funding

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this so I'm sorry if this is not.

I'm in a bit of a unique situation in that I am turning 17 this year and will soon be adopted. The person adopting me has a college education but from what I understand, the first generation college student is someone who's legal guardians have not gone to college but also exists to help those who enter college with a limited understanding of the jargon, traditions, and patterns of expected behavior.    My birth father left my mom and me when I was 3 and my mom never got a high school education in order to provide for her family and later me.  My question is then, do I qualify as a first generation college student because I believe I am everything it is except I will have a step father who has a college education.

Comment: Can you clarify? It sounds like you have one legal guardian who doesn't have a college education, but you will soon be officially adopted by your stepfather, who does. Is that correct?

Comment: I suggest you ask an institution that will need to make decisions based on whether you qualify for it or not and what advantage it gives if you do. This can vary widely be place and even by institution, I think.

Comment: This person who's adopting you - have they been a significant figure in your life for many years, or only relatively recently?

Comment: Following on Buffy, the real question is what individual schools or scholarships think one is. There seems to be much debate in educational/academic circles of what counts for what purposes.

Comment: I think you should decide for yourself if you qualify.  If you explain your situation, nobody's going to dispute what you decide.

Comment: I have been living with him for the past few years but even now I talk with him a few times a week at most and that's just saying good morning or good afternoon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extremely reasonable question, and the short answer is: what qualifies a student as almost any 'special box' in academic forms is a bureaucratic nightmare of conflicting interests, fuzzy or non-existent definitions, and what can in the end amount to guesswork - to the point that in the end the answer is that it [depends on who's asking](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/03/education/edlife/first-generation-college-admissions.html). There are apparently no less than three definitions provided used by the Department of Education. It's a mess.

Ultimately the only answer I can give is to check with the organization you are filling out forms with (University or otherwise) to clarify what they mean. It seems like common undergraduate admission apps use the definition of birth/biological parent having ever attained a college degree, but undergraduate admissions is generally off-topic here, so I'd still advise you to check with someone like an admission's officer or official program materials to see what their definition actually is. This is true for all future readers, as this technical definition may change in the future.

Note that for scholarship or diversity statement-related purposes, regardless of the technical definitions used, you are encouraged to mention your specific background in your own words, so you are not restricted to exactly what they mean by their terms.

I realize translating academese/legalese of this sort is a challenge generally, but this happens to be an area that is unusually difficult because there is no settled consensus and the definition of terms, and how they are used as decision factors, remains a hotly debated political topic (all the way to The Supreme Court, in fact).

Good luck in your educational journey!

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to check with my counselor as well as organizations I'm planning on filling out forms for what their definition of first generation college student is.